# How to use DictReader if I use islice from itertool to start at line 5?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with fieldnames that start from line 5.

For example,
line 5:
`Name,Age,Gender,Height`
line 6 and so on:
`Steve,31,M,190`

```py
with open('AGM.csv', 'r') as f2:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f2)

    for row in islice(csv_reader, 5, None):
        csv_DicReader = csv.DictReader(row)
        for lines in csv_DicReader:
            print(lines)
```

output was like this:

```
OrderedDict([('Name', 'Age')])

OrderedDict([('Name', 'Gender')])

OrderedDict([('Name', 'Height')])

OrderedDict([('Steve', '31')])

OrderedDict([('Steve', 'M')])

OrderedDict([('Steve', '190')])
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, Use:

```
import csv

with open('AGM.csv', 'r') as f2:
    for _ in range(4):
        next(f2) # skip first four lines

    # instantiate a dictreader after skipping first four lines
    reader = csv.DictReader(f2)
    for line in reader: # start reading from line 5
        print(line)
```

Or using `islice`,

```
with open('AGM.csv', 'r') as f2:
    reader = csv.DictReader(islice(f2, 4, None))
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

This prints:

```
{'Name': 'Steve', 'Age': '31', 'Gender': 'M', 'Height': '190'}
 ...
 ...
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Do you knowwhy is it that using itertools islice would give me the wrong output that i stated above?

Comment: @fluervion That's because You are creating new instance of dictreader every time and moreover there is no need to to use `csv.reader` Check the answer to find out proper way to use `islice`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are trying to do.

```
with open('AGM.csv', 'r') as f2:
    f = list(islice(f2, 4, None))
    csv_DicReader = csv.DictReader(f)

    for lines in csv_DicReader:
        print(lines)
```

Comment: This works perfectly with the islice function. Thanks!